# Using register method on field in other file

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, frontend, react-hook-form

I want to include in form  field wwhich is generate from Redux. In my case I generated it in other file and it look like this:

```
const PeopleContainer = ({ people }) => {
    const { register, errors } = useForm();

    return <select name="person_id" className="form-control" ref={register({ required: true })}>
        {people.list.map(person =>
            <option key={person.id} value={person.id}>{person.name}</option>
        )}
    </select>
    {
        errors.person_id&& (
            <Error alert="To nie jest prawidłowy typ sieci" />
        )
    }
}



const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    people: state.people
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PeopleContainer)
```

And in file form.js I add this field like this:

```
 <div className="row">
    <div className="col-12 col-md-2">
        <label>People</label>
     </div>
     <div className="col-12 col-md-10">
         <SelectPeople />
     </div>
 </div>
```

This code generate  correctly but doesn't send ajax request with values of this select. Is it simple way to solve my problem (send data with this field and valdiate) or maybe is other library which better that react-hook-form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after `FormProvider`:

https://react-hook-form.com/api#useFormContext

which you can have all your custom input hooked even deep nested.

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, FormProvider, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods} > // pass all methods into the context
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <NestedInput />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

function NestedInput() {
  const { register } = useFormContext(); // retrieve all hook methods
  return <input name="test" ref={register} />;
}
```